# Problems with 404, .htaccess, permalinks and Wordpress custom posts locally on Snow Leopard

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, archives, htaccess, 404-error

I have a custom "about" post:

```
function about_register() {
        $labels = array(
            'name' => _x('About Page', 'post type general name'),
            'singular_name' => _x('About Item', 'post type singular name'),
            'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'About Item'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New About Item'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit About Item'),
            'new_item' => __('New About Item'),
            'view_item' => __('View About Item'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Team'),
            'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
            'parent_item_colon' => ''
        );

        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => null,
            'has_archive' => 'about',
            'supports' => array('title','thumbnail')
        );

        register_post_type( 'custom_about_post' , $args );
    }
```

I created a page called archive-about.php and put my Wordpress loop in there and pulled up my custom meta information.

However, when I go to mysite.com/about I get a 404 error.

Searching the internet -

I went to my permalinks page and tried to flush rewrite rules by hitting save.

I was instructed to put the following into my sites .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite.com/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /iqfood/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

However, when I did this my entire site is now 403! If I remove this and leave my .htaccess file blank my site returns...but the link

```
localhost/mysite/about/
```

still doesn't work.

In order to make the archives work, do I use the default settings in permalinks or something else?

What should I be setting my rewrite rules to in Mac OSX (snow leopard) to run Wordpress locally?

Is there something wrong in the code posted above?

Comment: Have you flushed your rewrite rules by going to Settings/Permalinks and saving permalink structure?

Comment: Done that...it's in my description above.

Comment: Does my permalink structure have to be anything special or can I just use the default in order to see my custom post type archive?

Comment: Sorry, must have skimmed past over that line :) Seems like `'has_archive' => 'about'` is incorrect first of all, it has to be either `true` or `false`, refer to http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: That seems to be the main problem. Will add an answer shortly.

Comment: Nope, it can be a string, read the link again...it says (boolean or string)

Comment: It can, however, the `rewrite` will simply override that slug, so set to `true` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You named the custom post type `'custom_about_post'` not `'about'`. Rename the archive template to `archive-custom_about_post.php` or better: rename the post type.

As a rule of thumb: Avoid underscores in post type names. There are/were some issues, especially with templates.

And why do you need a custom post type just for about pages? What’s your goal?

Comment: The about page needs 9 separate text boxes with different content. I suppose I could just use a custom meta box...can I do that for a generic post? It's the only post I want the text boxes for

Comment: You could check if the post meta `_wp_page_template` matches your template and display the meta boxes only if it does.

Answer (score 1):

1. Permalinks has to be set to something other than default.
2. Maybe because I was on a Mac I had to set the following in my .htaccess file to get rid of the 403 error:

   Options +FollowSymLinks

So the entire rewrite file is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mysite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

As [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) shows, the `rewrite` argument is used incorrectly in your case. It has to be an array probably. The `slug` key would let you set your slug to *about* as required.

```
function about_register() {
    $args = array(
        ...
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'about' ),
        'supports' => array('title','thumbnail' )
    );

    register_post_type( 'custom_about_post' , $args );
}
```

Otherwise, as per:

> ...true and use post type as slug...

...your slug is being overridden.

Comment: Nope, didn't work